# Node request module Http.IncomingMessage not emitting events

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

According to this link: [request - Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#request-options-callback)

> The callback argument gets 3 arguments:
>
> An error when applicable (usually from http.ClientRequest object) An
>   http.IncomingMessage object The third is the response body (String or
>   Buffer, or JSON object if the json option is supplied)

Code:

```
var r = require("request");

var options= {
    url: "http://www.example.com/" 
};

var callback = function (err, res, body) {
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            console.log("DATA : "+chunk);
        });
        res.on("finish", function() {
            console.log("FINISHED");
        });
        console.log(body);
    }
};

r(options, callback);
```

But in the above code, only the `console.log(body)` works, the event emitters don't.

Also, if the callback would be invoked only when the whole response is body is available, then what's the point of making the second argument as `http.IncomingMessage`(Readable Stream) when I can't stream it.

Comment: What data are you expecting to get? If it's just the HTML returned from the URL, that's in `body` ?

Comment: I know that's in body. Then why is the the second argument as `http.IncomingMessage` with `data` and `finish` events with no use whatsoever. Why isn't it just a plain object with response parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a callback like that, `request` buffers the entire response for you and that is what is available in `body`. Because of this, that means you won't see `data` and such events on `res`, because they've already been taken care of by `request`.

Comment: I just thought that since it is an Http.IncomingMessage type object then it might have those events. I couldn't think of any other reason to make it of this type.

Comment: The response object is passed in because it contains things like `statusCode`, `headers`, etc. which are useful pieces of information in addition to the response body. It's easier/more efficient to just pass the original response object than to copy select properties from it to a new object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing two different ways to use the 'request' module. Depending on preference you can use either the callback approach or the streaming approach.

The callback approach involves passing a function as well as the options and when all the data is received it will call the callback function.

The streaming approach allows you to attach listeners to the events such as 'response'. I'm guessing you've mixed this code in from an example from receiving http requests and sending a response with a node server as I can't see any reference to 'data' and 'finish' events in the docs for the request module.

Comment: Yeah there is no mention in the docs. I just thought that since it is an `Http.IncomingMessage` type object then it might have those events. I coudn't think of any other reason to make it of this type.

Comment: As a guess it would be the same object they would return if you'd used the streaming approach, i.e. done `r(options).on('data', //etc`